# From string to XML

Tags: php, xml, string, t-sql, simplexml

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT CAST(CAST([xmlDoc] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT) AS xmlDoc FROM MYTABLE
```

xmlDoc is an xml. If I don't do the casting as TEXT I'll get this error:

Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

So, thanks to the casting as TEXT I don't have any problems and I go on with my application.

But now I need to parse the xml contained in xmlDoc. It was an xml but now it's a string.

How can I parse xmlDoc ? Can I return it to xml using any php function? What should I do?

I've tried:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_string($result['xmlDoc']);
```

But I get a FALSE for $mxl

Here's the string:

```
<Sent><Head><Application>T1</Application><NumSent U="052" yearg="2011" counter="0032"/><Date>2011-12-07</Date></Head><Content></Content></Sent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is just a fragment and I guess that SimpleXML expects a full XML document.

I know nothing about XML generation in SQL Server but in the PHP side you can always complete the document yourself:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_string(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $result['xmlDoc']
);
```